# Is it bad practice to use id for if/else conditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I have question on if/else condition , my database has saved region id 5657 that i am using to implement if/else conditions.

1- is it bad practice to use id ?

2- what is right way to implement if/else condition in this case ?

ctrl.js

```
if( geoLocation.items ) {
    $.each(geoLocation.parent(), function( index, location ) {
        if( location.id === 5657 ) {
            var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
            // Get the model
            var model = $parse( disableItemId );
            // Assigns a value to it
            model.assign( $scope, false );
        }
    });
    $.each( geoLocation.items, function( index, location ) {
        var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
        // Get the model
        var model = $parse( disableItemId );
        // Assigns a value to it
        model.assign( $scope, false );
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's bad practise to hardcode magic numbers.

Comment: Looks good to me, as long as your "magic number" (@Bergi) is semantic to/with the rest of your code, if using the number is logical to the developer who comes in behind you, your good to go. 1) if using an id selector gives you what you need your good to go, performance-wise if your selecting multiple elements that can be selected by using their DOM hierarchy or by class than the answer is obvious. Rule of thumb is to simply use the most appropriate selector. 2) I see nothing wrong with your `if` statements.

Comment: From what I can see, your loops are fairly pointless. The only benefit is that they make sure that item 5657 is in that array.
What are you trying to achieve? What is item 5657 and why are you targeting that one specifically?

Comment: @id.ot, I disagree.  Magic numbers should always be refactored.  So, I'm a new developer just looking at the code above... *if `location.id === 5657`... "hmm, well, okay."*

Comment: I also agree about not hard-coding magic numbers. There's gotta be a very good reason why no other solution will work.

Comment: Basically it is enable/disable functionality on checkboxes when checkbox global that has id 5657 is checked i am enabling and disabling other parents and childrens..

Comment: why are you using the DOM for all this in the first place? That's not the best practice for angular. Should be working with your data model, not the DOM. Then just change whatever properties `ng-model` are bound to

Comment: This is why 'best practice' questions can go sideways quickly. I disagree with you. For example if I have logic that looks for an element based on its ID and that ID that its looking for is defined server-side and the ID is found by returning results from a database and that db record stores the ID as a number (in many cases a composite ID from multiple db tables) and there are thousands of elements with the same class and DOM hierarchy, well there's a scenario anyway. In that case the dev's coming in behind you are going to have to defer to the code regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Ideally - at the data level for your locations, you would add a column/field called disabled or something, and flag the record(s) you want to hit that logic. Instead of using hard coded IDs, the code would look like:

```
if (location.disabled)
```

Of course if you don't have the access or ability to update the data source/objects you may be stuck doing it the way you have it there.